# build a map from Enum objects using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a Enum class:

```
public enum Fruits {
    Apple(0),
    Banana(1),
    // more objects
}
```

in another class, I need to create a map with key as all Enum values except `Apple`, value as a new `arrayList`.
I know how to do this in Java 7 :

```
Map<Fruits, List<Class<?>>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Fruits f : Fruits.values()) {
  if (!f.equals(Fruits.APPLE)) {
  fruitMap.put(f, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

I am learning java 8 now and really want to know how to write this using java 8.
I tried something :

```
Map<Fruits, List<Class<?>>> fruitMap = 

Arrays.stream(Fruits.values()).filter(e -> !e.equals(Fruits.Apple))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, new ArrayList<>()));
```

May anyone teach me how to write this in java 8.

Comment: Why did you try `.collect(Collectors.toMap(new ArrayList<>()))`? What do you think that is supposed to achieve?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far away. [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) expects two [`Functions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html):

```
Map<Fruits, List<Class<?>>> fruitMap = Arrays.stream(Fruits.values())
        .filter(e -> !e.equals(Fruits.Apple))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> new ArrayList<>()));
```